# How to get sql table output using select statement etc

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle sql i want output like below.
Column divided by row so put x and otherwise put blank ..

Example::-  1/100 so put x if not so put blank 
Can i do using select statement query in sql.
If 100 not division by 3 so put its blank..

```
XYZ  1  2  3  4  5  ...
--- -- -- -- -- --
100  ×  ×     ×  ×
200  ×  ×     ×  ×
300  ×  ×  ×  ×  ×
400  ×  ×     ×  ×
```

Its do all upto n column in database table.
Its do all upto n column in database table.

Its do all upto n column in database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using MOD(), like so:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 100 xyz FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 200 xyz FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 300 xyz FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 400 xyz FROM dual)
SELECT xyz,
       'x' "1", -- every number is divisible by 1
       CASE WHEN MOD(xyz, 2) = 0 THEN 'x' END "2",
       CASE WHEN MOD(xyz, 3) = 0 THEN 'x' END "2",
       CASE WHEN MOD(xyz, 4) = 0 THEN 'x' END "2",
       CASE WHEN MOD(xyz, 5) = 0 THEN 'x' END "2"
FROM   sample_data;

       XYZ 1 2 2 2 2
---------- - - - - -
       100 x x   x x
       200 x x   x x
       300 x x x x x
       400 x x   x x
```